# C# Get output from running processes

Tags: c#, process

Hello i need to read output from running process.
But the process, is running.

My Code is

```
Process[] p = Process.GetProcessByName("Server");
p[0].OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(Program_OutputDataReceived);
```

Void

```
static void Program_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("## " + e.Data.ToString());
    }
```

Console is empty. Does not show server message.

I not need to running process. Like Process.Start();
But i need only read message output in console from other running process.

Comment: You can only get this event when you start the process yourself and redirect the output. You can’t just connect to any process and read their stdout

Comment: oh, therefore there is no solution. Like application type putty SSH.

Comment: Well, the solution would be to start the process from the console and then redirect the output, as Sami has stated. If you are wanting to read from the `server` i.e. error messages, the server should have logs that you can read and output along with an event viewer/manager.